# Passing a user ID from a button to disable that user in the database

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to disable a users account by changing their activation field from 1 to 0 if a button is clicked.

This is my Route:

```
Route::post('admin/useradmin/{id}', array('as' => 'user-admin-disable-post', 'uses' => 'AdminController@postDisable'))->before('auth');
```

My Controller:

```
public function postDisable($id)
 {
  $user = User::find($id);

  $user = $user->first();

  $user->activate = 0; 

        if($user->save())
        {
            return Redirect::route('user-admin')
                    ->with('global', 'The users account has been disabled');
        }
        return Redirect::route('user-admin')
                ->with('global', 'Error disabling user account');
}
```

The View, this button that will be clicked, and then pass the users id to the controller to perform the action:

```
<a href="{{URL::route('user-admin-disable-post', $user->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs pull-left" style="margin-right: 3px;">Disable</a>
```

It's giving me a not found error when I click the button, and I see that the function is not being executed, how can I fix this?

Comment: sooooooooo...... what's the question?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to finish the question, @Gizmo The function is not being executed at all and it navigates to the view plus the user's id and says Not found

Comment: In your route, try starting the path with a slash like `/admin...`.

Comment: @AndréDaniel thanks, but I still get my error of "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" could it be that im using my route as a POST? or not?

Comment: The method `User::find($id)` will already return the user object, no need to call `$user->first();` afterwards.

Comment: Well yeah, your link means the browser will send a GET request. But you shouldn't use a GET request, since a GET shouldn't modify any data. Use a POST request and a form instead.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Just got that now! Took the first away and also made it a get.... BOOM! it works!! thanks guys! you can add it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The method `User::find($id)` will already return the user object, no need to call `$user->first();` afterwards. –  @martinstoeckli

I also changed the `post to get` in my routes.

This solved the issues I was having